# Book recommendations for spectral graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am working on a Natural Sciences related project, which involves graph theory. I have calculated the Laplacian and Adjacency spectra of my graphs and now have to interpret it.

However, I am not a mathematician and most books, that I have found, have quite a lot of proofs and theorems, which are indeed interesting, but not necessary for the interpretation of a spectra.

Maybe someone could recommend a book or an article that deals with the interpretation of the spectra? I am mostly interested in overall connectivity, topology, cycles, small-world or random structures and properties like that determination from the spectra of a graph.

Comment: I happened to notice that there is a book on the subject in this year's Springer Yellow Sale: [Spectra of Graphs | Andries E. Brouwer | Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461419389).

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, thank you, it's already in my reading list!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Spectra of graphs: theory and applications by Dragos M. Cvetkovic, Michael Doob, Horst Sachs;
2. http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/research/revised.html
3. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-6569-9
4. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/eigenspaces-of-graphs/3EB0B8BE4189DDE43005E311A5331523
5. https://www.elsevier.com/books/recent-results-in-the-theory-of-graph-spectra/cvetkovic/978-0-444-70361-3

You can go through the book by R.B. Bapat, the third link.

Answer (score 1):

How about these?

[Introduction to graph theory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Graph-Theory-Dover-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00BX1DX9U/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=dover%20books%20graph%20theory&qid=1587380149&sr=8-1)

[Introduction to Topology](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Topology-Third-Dover-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00ED6LHHM/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=dover%20books%20topology&qid=1587380227&sr=8-1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Joseph Hulme! However, I have already read similar book to "Introduction to graph theory" (it was M. van Steen "Graph Theory and Complex Networks: An Introduction") and I am interested in topology of the graphs themselves. Maybe you know something more graph theory related in terms of determining connectivity, topology, cycles or similar properties from the Laplacian or adjacency spectra of the graph?

Comment: I am not sure aerospace; maybe it is best to wait for someone more experienced in the subject as I am not so familiar with it. Sorry I couldn't be more help.